# Loggin the user and then saving the review - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this app where a user can write a review for a school. A user must sign in with Facebook to  save an review.

**The problem:**

If a user is unsigned and writes a review, then signs in with facebook they have to write the same review again.

I would like to handle it more like this: `unsigned user write a review, signs in with facebook and then the review is saved. But right now the user writes a review and then signs in and nothing is saved, the user have to write the review all over again`.`

How can do this? Any ideas or solution would be awesome!

**ReviewForm:**

```
<%= form_for [@school, Review.new] do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_area :content %>
    <% if current_user %>
      <%= f.submit 'Save my review', :class => "btn" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.submit 'Save my review and sign me into facebook', :class => "btn" %>
    <% end %>
<%end %>
```

**ReviewsController:**

```
    class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
        before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

        def create
            @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
            @review = @school.reviews.new(params[:review])

            @review.user_id = current_user.id

            if @review.save
                redirect_to @review.school, notice: "Review has been created."
            else
                render :new
            end
        end

        def new
            @school = School.find_by_id(params[:school_id])
            @review = Review.new
        end

        private 
        def signed_in?
            !current_user.nil?
        end

        def signed_in_user
            unless signed_in?   
                redirect_to "/auth/facebook"
            end
        end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good place to use an anonymous user.  Check out Ryan Bates's video on guest users at http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record.

Comment: this is pretty cool but I dont think it suits my application.

Answer (score 1):

The usual simple way to do this is save params into session before redirecting to authentication service. Once user authenticates you would check if those attributes are present and create the review.